# What do the stats on apparel mean in Starfield?

Tags: starfield

In Starfield, some apparel has stats, like this "Argos Extractor Jumpsuit":

[image: A screenshot of stats window for Argus Extractor Jumpsuit in Starfield]

They have labels, like *Phys*, *Engy*, *Thermal*, *Mass*, etc., but what exactly does this *mean* in terms of how it impacts my gameplay?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The top row of stats is the weapon resistance section.

- *PHYS* refers to *Physical Resistance*
- *ENGY* refers to *Energy Resistance*
- *EM* refers to *Electromagnetic Resistance*

These values indicate how much damage the apparel will resist, or soak, of each of those respective weapon damage types. In the case of your piece of apparel, it is best at protecting against physical weapons, like knives or projectile weapons, and least effective at protecting against energy weapons.

---

The second section indicates environmental protection:

- *THERMAL* refers to heat (like fire) resistance
- *AIRBORNE* refers to airborne contaminant (like diseases or pathogens) resistance
- *CORROSIVE* refers to caustic (like acid rain) resistance
- *RADIATION* refers to radioactive resistance

---

The third section indicates the mass (effective weight) of the object and its value. Your character will have a limited carry mass, so everything you pick up will add to that limit. Likewise, everything you can pick up has a value in the game's currency, credits.

---

The final section indicates any additional bonuses. Some apparel will have no bonuses. In your case, the *Argos Extractor Jumpsuit* gives you +5 maximum points to your Health and O2 (Oxygen) meters while worn.

---

The green and red coloration indicate changes vs what you currently have equipped.

In your case, *EM* is displayed in red, with an arrow pointing down beside it. This means what you currently have equipped provides more EM protection, and that more EM protection is better.

Likewise, Mass is displayed in green, with an arrow pointing down beside it. This means the *Argos Extractor Jumpsuit* is less mass (lighter) than what you currently have equipped, and that less mass is better.