# How can I see my suit protection level?

Tags: starfield

I am undertaking a mission on the planet Cassiopeia IV-A and it has a hostile environment.

The game suggests that my space suit can protect me from this environment based on it's stats, and I can see my totals in my character status under 'Character'

[image: Total suit stats]

However I do not see any on screen UI elements anywhere which tells me my suit protection level or amount?

I was hoping to see a gauge ticking down similar to No Man's Sky.

It seems my protection has run out somehow and I have contracted some conditions because of it.

[image: Burns, Lung Damage]

**How can I see if my suit protection has run out, to avoid getting a negative condition and what can I do to restore it?**

When out of a dangerous environment my protection regenerates, but other than this, I see no gauge or level of protection. So I do not know when to seek shelter, or how much time I have available.

[image: Protection regen]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the stats on apparel mean in Starfield?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404197/what-do-the-stats-on-apparel-mean-in-starfield)

Comment: @TylerH I think the OP is asking where to find those stats in the first place.

Comment: @Joachim They're stats on gear you have/equip, so... inventory.

Comment: So there is no UI element for this? Or an explainer to convert a suit stat of 10 Corrosion into a meaningful thing to know? Edited for clarity

Comment: My theory is that in atmospheres that are too hot or too cold, you'd want a high corrosion resistance suit, otherwise the suit's protection becomes depleted meaning you'll get damaged over time and status changes until you get indoors. I haven't found any great armors yet other than the mantis suit (just optimizing for storage). Maybe someone can go to Mars and swap armors to test out the theories.

Answer (score 1):

You will briefly see that your suit protection is failing when you are first exposed with your watch going red and telling you about the hazard, and when you are away from the hazard you will see a green indicator that your suit is recovering. I do not have any information on how much protection you get or whether a suit could make you immune to a given problem, but I imagine that it would be directly related to the strength of the hazard protection on the suite, so acid rain might not do anything on a suit with high corrosive resistance, but I am not sure. Agreed that it is annoying that there is no real indicator for whether your suit is protected or not. Something I have seen is that some hazards simply reduce suit protections, while others also provide information that you might suffer afflictions, and in my experience, as long as none of the hazards indicate that you could get afflictions you are probably fine ignoring it if you aren't going to expose yourself to other hazards like gas vents that can do stuff like the lung damage you see.

Comment: Hi Stephen, this seems like quite an elaborate comment that basically says "I don't know" to the OP's question. On this platform we try to avoid that kind of answer. Please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with it. Welcome to Arqade!